# AWS EC2 mutiple Instances with redundant data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I am noob, and just started learning about cloud computing and how AWS works.
Aws provide us the EC2 as service, Where I can run VM and put my data on top of it or say run my web server on top of the newly created instance.
I have seen people creating multiple instances in the same AZ.
Doesn't that leads to Redudant data, I mean we are creating more EC2 instances in the same AZ and putting the same data on each insances, so that when one gets called off, the client can access the data from another instance.
My question is this the industry practice to keep the redudant data (same data) across all the instances for better reachability or we are not putting the whole data on other instances just a fraction of it.
Please don't mind my stupid question, I am just learning.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when you run several instances of the same application, you run them in [autoscaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html) (ASG). For this, your applications should be **stateless**, as instances in ASG can be launched and terminated at any time automatically. To protect from data lose and ensure that new instances have access to existing data files, you don't store any user-data (e.g. user uploaded images) on the instances.

Instead you are going to store the data files **outside** of your instances. Common choices for that are [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) and [EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html). This solves the data redundancy issue, as you only have one copy of your files which can be accessed from all the instances. Also it protects your data from being lost if your instances will get terminated, as S3 and EFS are highly-available and fault resistant data stores managed by AWS.